# How to deploy Tomcat's example websocket applications?

Tags: tomcat, websocket, tomcat7

I am trying understand how to deploy the examples referenced in the Apache Tomcat 7 [WebSocket How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html) page.

The Application Development section advises reading javadoc on [WebSocketServlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/index.html?org/apache/catalina/websocket/WebSocketServlet.html) class. But looking at the [server side code of the examples](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/), none of the classes in the three examples `extend WebSocketServlet`, which is what I had expected it to do.

I am returning to servlet development after over a decade and feeling quite lost with all the annotations in these examples. Is there another How-To that has step-by-step simple instructions for getting a WebSocket using servlet up and running?

Comment: Haven't you seen this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568238/running-chat-xhtml-example-returns-info-websocket-closed ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[When you download the distribution of Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) (7.0.37 is the latest version at the moment), you will have the `examples` web application already deployed. It comes with the [WebSocket Examples](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html). You don't have to deploy it yourself.

Start Tomcat and open `http://localhost:8080/examples`.

[image: Apache Tomcat Examples]

Click **WebSocket Examples** and pick whatever WebSocket example you want.

[image: Apache Tomcat WebSocket Examples]

You don't have to do anything other than to start Tomcat with `bin/catalina.sh run` (or whatever command works for you).

When you look into `[TOMCAT_HOME]/webapps/examples` directory, you may want to look at `WEB-INF/web.xml` where you see the WebSocket servlets deployed.

Their source code is in `[TOMCAT_HOME]/WEB-INF/classes/websocket` directory.

The servlet `websocket.echo.EchoMessage` does extend `org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet`.

I wonder if I should have asked you about the version of Apache Tomcat you use? Perhaps you use some other not-so-recent version? I recommend to start with the latest version as it worked fine for me.

Comment: Oh, I haven't installed tomcat at all :) I was just looking at the code, I am using non-default embedded tomcat but I don't understand it much yet. I will try this out later, but it is what I am looking for so I will accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you like it. I should've asked about the version and where it came from. Thanks for encouraging me to give the WebSocket examples a try. I had been thinking about it for a long time!

Comment: Well I have already seen the example and the html at several places, I am hoping installing tomcat will help me understand the server side.

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski I am getting message like "Info: WebSocket closed.", in websocket/chat.xhtml. How to resolve that?

Comment: Sorry, not much WebSocket experience to answer your question.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar: It's the `timeout` which has been set in the examples. By default it is set to `20 secs`, so if your client remains idle more than the specified threshold, you loose the connection.

Answer (score -1):

start tomcat and go to url

```
/examples/websocket/echo.xhtml
```

select one of the two options annotation or progammatic API
change the url of the websocket to

```
/examples/websocket/echo.xhtml
```

and don't use the default that was in .

Comment: I always get message like "Info: WebSocket closed.", in websocket/chat.xhtml. How to resolve that?