# Websocket compilation error

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I have installed tomcat7 on my ubuntu machine and I have been trying to experiment with websockets. I have also installed tomcat examples, docs etc but I dont see the web socket example under the examples folder.
[How to deploy Tomcat's example websocket applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443550/how-to-deploy-tomcats-example-websocket-applications)
Also, I tried a test application that was importing javax.websocket.* but it threw an error:
package javax.websocket does not exist

Is there any thing that I have done wrong and is there a good way to approach websockets