# running chat.xhtml example returns: Info: WebSocket closed

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

Team,

1) I downloaded "`apache-tomcat-7.0.52`" to my windows 7 (32 bit machine); 
2) Then i ran `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\bin\startup.bat` 
3) Now trying `http://localhost:8080/examples/websocket/chat.xhtml` on chrome browser, I am getting

> Info: WebSocket closed

in the big textArea.

localhost_access_log.2014-03-22.txt shows the below.

127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2014:01:22:01 +0530] "GET /examples/websocket/chat.xhtml HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2014:01:22:02 +0530] "GET /examples/websocket/chat HTTP/1.1" 404 997

```
C:\Users\ksugumar>java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

I am new to WebSocket, and want to try the TOMCAT examples. Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark from APACHE team has pointed out me that;

Though i installed jre7; my system property for JRE_HOME is 1.6 java version. So it is not working.

Identified through

```
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\bin>catalina.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\temp"
**Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"**
```

Also from the ***catalina.2014-03-25.log*** states

> INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available
>   when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java
>   7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the
>   WebSocketJARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip
>   property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the
>   deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available.